# Playlist questions for new iTunes update

Tags: iphone, itunes

I recently upgraded to the new 7.0 iPhone/iTunes update and am aggravated because my purchased music is included in playlists when I do not choose them. I have a lot of music that I have purchased just to complete a collection. I want only to play what I choose. How do you get them off the playlist and keep them from playing?

Answer (score 1):

Don't be aggravated, take a trip into settings where you can quickly and easily turn this off.

`Settings > Music > Show All Music:` **ON** / **OFF**

This settings toggles between:

> All music that has been downloaded or that is stored in iCloud will be shown

and

> Only music that has been downloaded to this device will be shown.

*Now you're sorted, go for a run and wind down* ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's under the "view" menu in settings that provides a choice between "all music" and "only downloaded music"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  This question is several years old, does your answer apply to the version of iTunes the OP specified?  We prefer that answer be more than 1 sentence and they should include the reasons why your suggested solution will work.  Please see [answer] for info on what makes a good answer.  - From Review